# Whenever i try moving button it gives me XML error at runtime

Tags: android, xml

In my android app I have 3 buttons(suppose A,B and C). But whenever i try to move button B anywhere on the screen i get run time XML error.(no compile time error)

If i put it back to its original position it works fine.

Thanks.

I have one multiline textfield that is only visible when i click button A. 
I think whenever i move button B this textfield also moves with it and whenever i move button B more close to the bottom i get this error.
If this is the case then is there any way to remove this dependency?

Comment: I dont have 10 reputation to post images else i would have shown u my screenshot

Comment: Try posting your code, how you are trying to move button.?

Comment: By dragging it. I am doing it graphically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are using the graphical builder with ADT. After you move your buttons just give a look at the xml structure if the syntax is correct after the you have moved the buttons. There must be some syntax error causing the runtime XML error.

Also prefer editing the xml than using Graphic Builder for positioning after you have dropped the required elements in the layout.

Comment: ok. That helped. actually my textfield is having this attribute android:layout_below="@+id/button2" ..so i had to remove this and dependency is gone. Thanks mate